# I have AAPt error on my Android xml file: Tag <category> attribute has invalid character

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have an Android xml file that includes splash and one another activity ım planıng to pass one to another while using ınytent in this context I created a default and launcher category
but eclipse is giving me error that: Tag <category> attribute has invalid character 
(actually there is no invalid character)
here is my xml code 
(boldline is the line that error occurred)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tesbih"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.tesbih.TesbihMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
            **<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT "** />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name="com.tesbih.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>

</manifest>
```

here is also my logcat
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The value of the local variable timer is not used   Splash.java /Tesbih/src/com/tesbih  line 15 Java Problem
Tag  attribute name has invalid character ' '.    AndroidManifest.xml /Tesbih line 21 Android AAPT Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason of thıs problem is a bug that bundle has. if you  save everythıng and exit 
then when you open agaın  you should go your xml fıle after makıng anychanges on the name of android name you can save and re exit again when you open your eclipse and android manifest your  error sign will be lost